# I have started in react but when I am typing npm start it gives these set of error mesaages

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\tarun\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tarun\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tarun\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-20T09_05_27_487Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Looks like you are running npm start outside of a react project

Answer (score 1):

As is apparent from the error message, `npm` cannot find a `package.json` file in your current directory (which is `C:\Users\tarun`).

Most probably you are not running the command from the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command inside the directory of package.json file.